# Wordpress, ACF woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I use Wordpress, woocommerce and ACF (freeversion)
I created new user field buy ACF 'youtube_chanel',

I added this code to the template form_edit_account.php

```
<?php
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $options = array(
                    'post_id' => 'user_'.$current_user_id,
                    'fields' => array('youtube_chanel'),
                    'form' => true,
                    'instruction_placement' => 'label',
                    'submit_value' => __("Save changes ", 'acf'),
                );
        acf_form($options);
```

?>

The code displays the field correctly, but  I cant save the changes.

Can you help please !

Answer (score 0):

Use the hook below which trigger before saving the post to update your custom fields.

```php
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post');

function my_acf_save_post( $post_id ) {

    // Get newly saved values.
    $values = get_fields( $post_id );

    // Check the new value of a specific field.
    $youtube_channel = get_field('youtube_channel', $post_id);
    if( $youtube_channel ) {
        // Do something...
    }
}
```

[From ACF documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/)

Comment: Thank you sir for your help, but it does not work. I am new at Wordpress,.